# Google Analytics. Contradiction with New vs Returning and Time to purchase

Tags: google-analytics

Today I encountered strange observation in the analytics data of one of my clients.

The data are for may this year.
1) New vs Returning report shows twice as many transactions for returning as for new (which looks logical).
2) Days to purchase report shows almost 90 % of transactions on the first day.

Any ideas why it can be like this or what can be wrong?

Comment: are you comparing standard reports and multi-channel reports?

Comment: Petr, didn't get your question. I'm comparing 2 standard reports.